# Grid and design guidelines for 3D system icons?

Tags: icon, interface-design, 3d, grids, maya

I'm experimenting with 2D interfaces for 3D design and spatial interfaces and looking for some guidelines such as material design

[image]

[image]

Note: I'm not talking about 3d icons in general (style) but icons which its primary function are related to a spatial action, for example creating a cylinder in a 3d space

[image]

It looks like the major players such as autodesk are not following a design standard / consistency themselves

Comment: Autodesk is not following material design. Just because the design are flat does not mean they follow googles guides

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want guidelines for designing icons for 3D applications? Or how to apply material design to these 3D system icons?

Comment: Hi joojaa, I know that. But their icons are not consistent between themselves.

Comment: Hey Luciano. I'm am looking for a comprensive guideline such as IOS or material design including icon grid, line thickness, rules for rounded corners, boundaries for icons for 3d applications. If you apply a flat design for "create a sphere" icon you might end up getting a circle? unless you use some filled icon and apply a gradient to imply fake lighting? I thinl that probably a isometric guideline would be best?

Comment: @DanielVianna I dont think its a good idea to put the guidelines for the orientation of the 3D. The grid is there to tell you how to fill the space. But there are reasons why you will want the icon to have different orientations and adding all those lines will make the thing clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Graphisoft recently redesigned their legacy UI for ArchiCAD, replacing the dated and clunky pixel art with a smoother, more elegant SVG icon set - and it definitely has a clear set of guidelines, though it also pays strong service to the existing set's generated expectations - I'd suggest you look it over.

https://www.behance.net/gallery/54319379/Graphisoft-Archicad-icon-set-design